# AnimationDrawable in RecyclerView item not animating on notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged, animationdrawable

I have a recyclerview whenever i select an item in recyclerview to play music i need to animate my AnimationDrawable equalizer of selected item but it is not animating when i call notifyDataSetChanged to refresh my view to show equalizer on selected item.

Comment: did you fix this?