# ProgressBar in RecyclerView item not animating on notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I see a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47574529/animationdrawable-in-recyclerview-item-not-animating-on-notifydatasetchanged)
AnimationDrawable in RecyclerView item not animating on notifyDataSetChanged.
But couldn't resolve this issue or fix. I think its because notifyDataSetChanged call multiple times to update UI. While I comment or notification change call for the position it works fine.
I have three items in the recycled view.

1. Progress bar
2. Text view
3. Button

I need to call an API on button click and increment the textview value. while API calls I need to show the progress bar and hide while API finish

Button click as follow,

```
holder.image_add_overlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            holder.progressBar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);             
            UpdateProductItem(holder, position);
        }
    });

private void UpdateProductItem(ShoppinglistAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    try {
        Boolean value = CartFunctions.UpdateCartPostValue(cartAdd, mAPIService);
        if (value) {
            holder.text_item_cart_count.setText("" + holder.cart_count_value);
                // notifyDataSetChanged();
                holder.progressBar2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Task task = new Task();
                task.execute(); 
            Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.cart_update_toast_message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            holder.cart_count_value = holder.cart_count_value - 1;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I also try the

```
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
public class Task extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... strings) {
        Log.i("test", "doInBackground");
        // notifyDataSetChanged();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
        Log.i("test", "onPostExecute");
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        super.onPostExecute(integer);
    }
}
```

And call the this using

```
Task task = new Task();
//task.doInBackground();
task.onPostExecute(0);
```

May the 2 item in recyclerview are same, so the count is shown to both become same. so i need notifyDataSetChanged() instead of notifyItemChanged(position);
Did any guys know the solution?

Comment: call notifyDataSetChanged() in onPostExecute() method

Comment: I will try and update you

Comment: What's the point of your `AsyncTask`?

Comment: @Vij i try with onPostExecute() ,but still the issue be same

Comment: Please add data related to `Progressbar` or `RecyclerView.Adapter` or `Activity`.

Comment: @buzzingsilently  i update the question, progress bar to just Visibility to Visible and Gone. Also, the text view to show the incremented data. I need notifyDataSetChanged() because i need to refresh entire adapter data

Comment: Add code for Button Click and work you are doing on API response.

Comment: Please check the question

Comment: Now why do you need `notifyDataSetChanged()`?, Progressbar is VISIBLE & GONE at right places.

Comment: I set the basics of my program in question, but in reality the data updated from other place and need to refresh all the updated value . may the 2 item in recyclerview are same, so the count is shown to both become same. so i need notifyDataSetChanged() instead of notifyItemChanged(position);

Comment: I feel using `interface` for RecyclerView item click will be better solution, refere this link. Implement onClick using interface. API calling & response in Activity class. DO NOT play with holder out side of Adapter bind method.

Comment: @buzzingsilently link not included,  link, please

Comment: sorry, here it is https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/

Comment: @buzzingsilently why u delete your answer?

Comment: it might be problem with arraylist that defined when insert or update your arraylist , make sure you made only single instance of list

Comment: @Vij I think it's not related to ArrayList because I check it with 3 diff Adapter and ArrayList. But still the same issue

Answer (score 1):

`doInBackground()` method works in a separate thread, not even on UI thread.

Notify your adapter on UI thread, From `AsyncTask` : `onPreExecute()` & `onPostExecute()` method works on UI thread.

```
public class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Call your Task using,

```
Task task = new Task();
task.execute();
```

Refer [AsynkTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) for more details.

Comment: i update the question, let go through that, I still face the issue

Comment: BTW, I have a doubt, Why do you need `AysncTask` here?

Comment: How do you get adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in onPostExecute().

Comment: Without AysncTask can we achive the ProgressBar in RecyclerView item not animating on notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: Yes, I think it has nothing to do with `AsyncTask`.